# ¿Cómo puedo crear una vista previa de un archivo en SharePoint Microsoft 365?

Tags: pdf, vistas, microsoft-office, sharepoint

necesito crear una vista previa para los archivos en pdf en SharePoint. Los archivos pdf al quedar guardados en mi OneDrive los puede ver sin problema. Pero cuando los quiero abrir directamente en mi sitio Sharepoint, me aparece esto (imagen). He tratado seguir configuraciones, pero ninguna me ha funcionado, o me sugieren opciones que no me aparecen para realizar la configuración.

Desde ya, muchas gracias por su ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En general, SharePoint es diligente creando la vista previa por su cuenta. Prueba usando un nombre de archivo más corto, refrescando la pestaña de tu navegador y/o dándole un tiempo de espera hasta que cree la vista previa y la deje disponible (a veces pareciera que el CDN tarda en dejar visible esa vista previa)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. Lo intenté, pero no funcionó. Quizás sea un problema en el flujo que realicé

Comment: Hm, SP lo identifica como PDF por el icono, pero puede que algo en la metadata no func. Si subes manualmente el mismo PDF qué pasa? Si subes manualmente otro PDF de nombre más corto, qué pasa?

Comment: Probé generándolo manualmente pero no me funciona. Esto es porque me estoy trayendo los post mediante un flujo de power automate a  mi sitio sharepoint. El cuerpo del post se ve ok pero las imágenes no se visualizan

Comment: Las imágenes no están embebidas en los posts. Habría que ajustar el flujo para que identifique los `<img> y los reemplace por la imagen correspondiente (que estará almacenada en algún lugar del sitio) antes de generar el PDF o que genere el PDF a partir del HTML ya completo